# can I use "Bus rider" for "Bus passenger"?

Tags: meaning

I want to write something about bus public transit and I want to know weather it is common to use the term "Bus rider" for "bus passenger"?

Comment: Depends on context.  Generally they'd be considered to be the same, but it depends to a degree on the weather.

Comment: In Britain you would be unlikely to hear *bus rider*. We *ride* bicycles and *motor bikes*, and we take a *ride* on a bus, or in a car. But *passengers* are never *riders*. Interestingly I first remember hearing *bus rider* used in the 1950s during the American Civil Rights protests, when they sang their famous song about *ridin' de bus, on freedom's right line*.

Comment: You could ask Burton Cummings [what he thinks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=615OiJFQooM)?

Comment: I would say they are interchangeable to refer to someone currently on the bus, but *bus rider* is how someone who uses the bus as a regular or primary mode of transportation would describe himself. Every bus passenger is not necessarily a bus rider. U.S. advocacy groups for regular users of the bus are invariably *Bus Riders Unions*, not *Bus Passengers' Associations*. Perhaps *rider* has an air of agency that parallels with *car driver*. People who are primarily car passengers don't call themselves passengers either; they are *carpoolers* or *ride-sharers*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the local wording here, in Ottawa, Canada, is usually "rider" or "transit user" (as we have buses and a train).